# Want to get aggerate nested documents count as per nested query from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

Sample Index mapping:

```
employee : {
  smallcase: {
    type: "nested",
    ...
    stock: {
      type: "nested"
    }
  }
}
```

Note: this is not my actual index. it is just sample

Documents will be like:

```
employee: {
  
  smallcase: [{
    
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "s1"
    .....
    stock: [
     {
       name: "A1",
       type: "sector"
       ....
     }
    ]
  }
  
  ...............
  ...............
  ]
}
```

To fetch all the stocks count  for employee "e1"

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "e1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": "0",
  "size": "0",
  "aggs": {
    "count": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "smallcase.stock"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Through above query I will be able to get stocks count for employee "e1"
But I want to use nested query as well .

Question:

- Want to fetch count of stocks whose name = "A1" and type ="sector" for employee "e1".

Note: fetching only for a single employee only but it may have multiple small cases. [ Using elasticsearch 7.x version]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer.

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [
        "e1"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "stock": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "smallcase.stock"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "inner": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "smallcase.stock.type": "sector"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match": {
                    "smallcase.stock.name": "A1"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiple [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) combined with the bool query

Adding a working example with index data, index mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "employee": {
        "properties": {
          "smallcase": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "stock": {
                "type": "nested"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "employee": {
    "smallcase": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "s1",
        "stock": [
          {
            "name": "A1",
            "type": "sector"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
{
  "employee": {
    "smallcase": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "s2",
        "stock": [
          {
            "name": "A2",
            "type": "sector"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
{
  "employee": {
    "smallcase": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "s1",
        "stock": [
          {
            "name": "A2",
            "type": "sector"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "from": "0",
  "size": "0",
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "employee.smallcase",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "employee.smallcase.name": "s1"
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "employee.smallcase.stock",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": {
                      "match": {
                        "employee.smallcase.stock.name": "A1"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "count": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "employee.smallcase.stock"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "count": {
      "doc_count": 1
    }
  }
```

Comment: @rathod151 did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :-)

Comment: I have already tried this query before submitting this question. but it wasn't working.
like if stocks are a1,a2,a3 at that time it should have given me only 1 count but it was giving me 3 count.

will try with smallcase filter as well.

Comment: @rathod151 sorry, I didn't get you. I have added a working example in the answer above, is the search result shown above same as what you expect to get ? And please share a proper format of your sample index data and index mapping

Comment: @rathod151 can you please reply back to my previous comments ?

Comment: I have tried your query that you have given, it doesn't give right output.
Usecase:
  employee e1 -> 4 smallscase 
   Every smallcase -> 5 stocks 
So I want to find total stocks of "sector" type in specified small case .
Exmaple: 
  e1 -> s1 -> 5 stocks but from 5 only 2 are sector type then
I just want count as "2"

Comment: @rathod151 okay, bu atleast share a proper format of your sample index data and index mapping

Comment: Please check the answer what I was looking for